# WordPress Error "Error in moving the item to Trash "

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm trying to move the page to trash but it's not working. Instead of page deletion page redirected to notification "Error in moving the item to Trash".

Trying to delete page but error appeared.

Comment: Check the console error in browser. you can use ctrl+shift+i